# IOS Objective C Draw Bitmap on View

Tags: objective-c, bitmap, draw

Im using the following to display a jpg on a view in Drawrect as follows

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

UIImage *anImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagetest.jpg"];
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(440,140, 140, 187);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGPathRef clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageFrame cornerRadius:30].CGPath;
CGContextAddPath(ctx, clippath);
CGContextClip(ctx);
[anImage2 drawInRect:imageFrame];
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

This works Perfect However I need to load the image from the sandbox. If I change the code to the following

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDir, @"imagetest.jpg"];    
UIImage *anImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed: pngFilePath];
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(440,140, 140, 187);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGPathRef clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageFrame cornerRadius:30].CGPath;
CGContextAddPath(ctx, clippath);
CGContextClip(ctx);
[anImage2 drawInRect:imageFrame];
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

Now Nothing shows up

I Have checked and the image path is correct and the file exists and it is he same jpg that is in the bundle so I can’t understand where I’m going wrong

Any Ideas?

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed]` does not accept a path to an image, it only accepts an image name.  Try `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`.  Apple's docs state that method "creates and returns an image object by loading the image data from the file at the specified path."

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried  UIImage *anImage2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];  but it still doesn't show anything

Comment: sorry an Slog of pngFilePath shows the path as /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EE7716E4-6514-4348-B991-AB779E29DF39/Documents/imagetest.jpg when i check if this file exists it does

Comment: This is off the top of my head so I'm sorry if it's not 100% correct.  (Sorry for formatting looking bad, on my iPhone)

`NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:@"imagetest.jpg"]];
UIImage *anImage2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help spot on Mark